# Basic String Operations

Tags: java, string

I am trying to replicate some basic operations of strings and the code works it just doesn't print the output using the `StringBuilder` function

```
public static String concatenation(String a, String b) {

    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        //System.out.println(a.charAt(i));
        str.append(a.charAt(i));
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < b.length(); j++) {
        //System.out.println(b.charAt(j));
        str.append(b.charAt(j));
    }

    String concat = str.toString();
    return concat;
}

public static String subString(String a, int i, int j) {

    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

    for (int k = i; k <= j; k++) {
        //System.out.println(a.charAt(k));
        str.append(a.charAt(k));
    }

    String sub = str.toString();

    return sub;
}
```

In both cases the `System.out.println()` works and prints the correct output but it does line by line and I need it in one string which is why I am using the `StringBuilder` but its not working for some reason.

In the main method i have:

```
    a = scan.nextLine();
    b = scan.nextLine();
    String concat = concatenation(a, b);
```

Comment: Are you printing the returned values? Please post your main method, or whatever method these functions return to.

Comment: Use `print()` instead of `println()` ?

Comment: Why not `return new StringBuilder(a).append(b).toString();`?

Comment: using print() works I just want to understand why the StringBuilder does not work

Comment: The concatenation works fine when I try it. Pure copy paste into eclipse.

Comment: maybe its something with IntelliJ then, weird

Comment: Just copied it into IntelliJ, works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just want to understand why the StringBuilder does not work

As far as I can see, there is nothing wrong with the either `StringBuilder` or your `concatenation` method.

```
a = scan.nextLine();
b = scan.nextLine();
String concat = concatenation(a, b);
```

I think problem is that you have simply assigned the result of the `concatenation` method call to a variable *and not printed it out*.  Add this after the last of those 3 lines:

```
System.out.println(concat);
```

---

> In both cases the System.out.println() works and prints the correct output but it does line by line and I need it in one string

That is because you are using `println`.  The `println` method outpust its argument followed by a line termination.  If you don't want the line termination, then use `print` instead.

HOWEVER, the `concatenation` method shouldn't be printing anything, if it is supposed to be an analogue of `String.concat`.  You should be printing the concatenated string *after* it has returned by the `concatenation` method.

Answer (score 0):

Change Your `concatenation(String a, String b)` as like this. A much better approach to achieve I think.

```
  public static String concatenation(String a, String b) {

    StringBuilder str1 = new StringBuilder(a);
    StringBuilder str2 new StringBuilder(b);    
    str1.append(str2);
       return str1.toString();
}
```

and you can use this for `subString(String a, int i, int j)`

```
public static String subString(String a, int indexFirst, int indexLast) {

    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    char[] arr = a.toCharArray();
      if(arr.length < indexFirst || arr.length > indexLast)
          throw new Exception ("Invalid Index Out of Bound Found Exception");
    for (int k = i; k <= j; k++) 
        str.append(arr[k]); // this looks better than manipulating any String because of Immutability Property. 

    return str.toString();
    }
```

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to mention it in the description. The task is to show how the concatenation or substring methods are performed by languages without using predefined functions such as the simple "+" or ".". Which is why I went for the unnecessarily complicated method of the for loops